# Generate equal distributed Odd and Even number

Tags: python, random

I am running an hourly job for each run I am generating a random number, using that random number for branching the logic by checking whether the random number is odd or even. But I don't want a sequence of odd and even. for example, I need a random of odd and even.

Example

```
Hour, Random number(between 1 and 2)
0, odd
1, even
2, even
3, even
4, odd
5, even
```

at end of each day run, there should be an equal number of odd and even

Comment: If you want at end of each day run an equal number of odd and even, you'll have to save state between executions of your script. For example, you could generate a random shuffle of 24 numbers in the beginning of the day and consume this list throughout the day (e.g. `x=list(range(24)); random.shuffle(x)`). But without saving state between executions, there is no way to **guarantee** that the number of runs will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact split between even numbers and odd ones, generate half the set as evens, half the sets as odds, concatenate the two subsets, and shuffle.

Even numbers are easy to generate. If you have a set of integers `[0, 1, 2, 3,...]`, doubling them will yield even values `[0, 2, 4, 6,...]`. If you want the output to start with 2 rather than 0, add one before doubling. Similarly, to get odd numbers all you have to do is double any integer and then add one. You can different numbers of levels for the evens and odds by simply adjusting the range of values used as inputs.

The following code illustrates these concepts in the form of a generator. The default parameterization generates 1's and 2's for 24 hour days, as per your problem statement, but that's easily adjusted. Below I've used 6-hour days to make it easier for readers to confirm that the results have equal numbers of odds and evens. Each call to `next(gen)` coughs up a new day's worth of observations.

```python
from random import randrange, shuffle

# Default parameterization produces equal numbers of 1's and 2's
def evens_n_odds(even_levels = 1, odd_levels = 1, hours_per_day = 24):
    half_day = hours_per_day // 2       # Rounds down if odd
    while True:
        odd_data = [2 * randrange(odd_levels) + 1 for _ in range(half_day)]
        even_data = [2 * (randrange(even_levels) + 1) for _ in range(half_day)]
        one_day = odd_data + even_data
        shuffle(one_day)
        yield(one_day)

# Override default parameterization for demo purposes:
#   Evens will be elements from {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
#   Odds will be elements from {1, 3, 5}
#   There will be 3 each of evens and odds
gen = evens_n_odds(even_levels = 5, odd_levels = 3, hours_per_day = 6)

# Print 5 days worth of even/odd values with the given parameterization
for day in range(5):    
    print(next(gen))
```

This parameterization of the code generates 5 days (rows) of 6 observations per day (columns), with evens occurring in the range 2..10 and odds in the range 1..5, yielding outputs such as:

```text
[3, 10, 6, 3, 3, 8]
[5, 10, 1, 4, 5, 8]
[2, 3, 8, 3, 3, 8]
[6, 10, 1, 4, 5, 1]
[6, 4, 10, 3, 5, 5]
```

If the explanation was unclear, hopefully the code sheds some light. It's easy to confirm that each day has equal numbers of evens and odds, but their magnitudes and ordering are random.

Answer (score 0):

### A possible interface:

The *hourly job* will essentially requires a function that returns a random boolean value, to be interpreted as either even type processing or odd type processing.

The function could be named `isOddProcessingHour`, with this interface:

```
def isOddProcessingHour():
```

However, in order to be able to run statistical sanity checks easily, we can instead have a function that can take explicit day (counted since some arbitrary *epoch*) and hour (in [0..23]) arguments. The function will default to *current* day and hour whenever no explicit arguments are provided. See example of use in the short interactive test session further below.

So we can have the code:

```
import  datetime
import  numpy  as  np


def getCurrentDayAndHour():
    now   = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour  = now.hour
    epoch = datetime.date(2019, 12, 31)  # Jan 1st, 2020 as day #1
    toDay = datetime.date.today()
    delta = toDay - epoch
    day = delta.days
    return (day, hour)


# returns an isOdd boolean value, with day and hour defaulting to current values:
def isOddProcessingHour(day=None, hour=None):
    if (day is None  or  hour is None):
        day, hour = getCurrentDayAndHour()
    return isOddProcessingHour2(day, hour)


# returns an isOdd boolean value, explicit day and hour being required:
def isOddProcessingHour2(day, hour):
    oddHours = getOddProcessingHours(day)
    if (hour in oddHours):
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

With such a setup, the main job has to be done by the `getOddProcessingHours()` function that just takes a day value (counted since the epoch) and returns a pseudo-random list of 12 hour values between 0 and 23.

### A possible strategy:

In order to have proper statistical guarantees about generated boolean values, we will use a single pseudo-random serie, that is we do **NOT** want each hourly job to start independently its own generator.

This is obtained by using the fact that, for a fixed value of the *random seed*, the pseudo-random values generated are reproducible. So all hourly jobs will use the same seed and hence the same serie, but each such job simply peeks its values at a different offset in the serie.

This approach might look costly, as each hourly job has to recompute all previous pseudo-random values, but in practice the time taken is very small; of course, this is greatly helped by having the main loop on days run inside the Numpy library and not within interpreted Python code.

And the good points are:

1. we have no need to store any generator state in the file system
2. we have statistical fairness guarantees for our pseudo-random boolean values

We proceed by generating random permutations of the [0..23] sequence, using the [`permuted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html) method offered by Numpy generators. After the permutation, the leftmost 12 values are taken to be the ones getting odd processing.

So we have the following Numpy code:

```
# returns a random list of 12 hour numbers between 0 and 23,
# as a function of day (day 0 being some epoch)
def getOddProcessingHours(day):
    randomSeed = 42434445
    rng = np.random.default_rng(randomSeed)

    # create 2D Numpy array with (1+day) identical rows containing [0..23]
    hours24   = np.array(range(24))
    allHours0 = np.reshape(np.tile(hours24, 1+day), [1+day,24])

    # run the random permutations:
    allHours1 = rng.permuted(allHours0, axis=1)

    oddHours = sorted(list(allHours1[day])[0:12])
    return oddHours
```

If for some reason, the user prefers to get a list of 24 odd or even numbers, this is easily arranged:

```
def getRandomOddEvenNumbers(day):
    oddHours = getOddProcessingHours(day)
    numbers  = 24*[2]
    for hr in oddHours:
        numbers[hr] = 1
    return numbers
```

**Testing:**

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.13 (main, May 18 2022, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2)] on linux
...
>>> 
>>> getOddProcessingHours(118)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 16, 19, 21, 23]
>>> 
>>> getOddProcessingHours(1000)
[0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 18, 20]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> getCurrentDayAndHour()
(923, 11)
>>> 
>>> getOddProcessingHours(923)
[0, 5, 8, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22]
>>> 
>>> getRandomOddEvenNumbers(923)
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
>>> 
>>> isOddProcessingHour(923,11)
True
>>> 
>>> isOddProcessingHour()
True
>>>
```

### Running some sanity checks:

The code is now complete, and we can thus write some statistical sanity checks for it, say for the first 1000 days after the epoch:

```
#
# -- Main Program - statistical sanity checks:
#

dayCount = 1000
perHourOddFlagCounts = 24*[0]

unbalancedDayCount = 0

for d in range(dayCount):
    oddHourCount = 0
    for hr in range(24):
        if isOddProcessingHour2(d,hr):
            perHourOddFlagCounts[hr] += 1
            oddHourCount += 1
    if (oddHourCount != 12):
        unbalancedDayCount += 1

print("")

totalOddCount = 0
for hr in range(24):
    print("hour = %02d  oddCount = %6d"  %  (hr, perHourOddFlagCounts[hr]))
    totalOddCount += perHourOddFlagCounts[hr]

print("\ntotalOddCount=%d"  %  totalOddCount)
print("\nunbalancedDayCount=%d"  %  unbalancedDayCount)
```

**Test output:**

```
hour = 00  oddCount =    481
hour = 01  oddCount =    516
hour = 02  oddCount =    488
hour = 03  oddCount =    517
hour = 04  oddCount =    492
hour = 05  oddCount =    517
hour = 06  oddCount =    482
hour = 07  oddCount =    500
hour = 08  oddCount =    493
hour = 09  oddCount =    476
hour = 10  oddCount =    505
hour = 11  oddCount =    473
hour = 12  oddCount =    512
hour = 13  oddCount =    512
hour = 14  oddCount =    506
hour = 15  oddCount =    494
hour = 16  oddCount =    500
hour = 17  oddCount =    518
hour = 18  oddCount =    508
hour = 19  oddCount =    524
hour = 20  oddCount =    498
hour = 21  oddCount =    505
hour = 22  oddCount =    507
hour = 23  oddCount =    476

totalOddCount=12000

unbalancedDayCount=0
```

So, as expected, all days are exactly balanced with 12 “odd processing” hours. And for each hour value between 0 and 23, the number of the “odd processing” jobs fluctuates around the expected average of 1000/2 = 500.